# Why do my rigid bodies freak out after adding one more object?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Trying to rig the mesh hair to have physics. It works fine, until I add one more (passive) rigid body (the opaque cube) to the scene. Any idea what may cause this?

https://streamable.com/g3lhak

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried applying scale, location, and rotation to the bones and objects? Select them and Ctrl+A.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I did align the axes of the objects to the axes of the bones.